# I am getting a failed login message in the SQL Server error logs however, nothing actually failed?

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, error-log, crystal-reports

I have a server which runs third party software (called Visualcut) to email Crystal Reports to our users.

When I log onto the Visualcut Server, I can open the software and then preview a report. This will ask me to enter a username and password (for an Microsoft SQL account) and then the report will display with no errors however, whenever I do this, an error is logged in the SQL Server error logs as follows:

> 10/26/2015 08:15:39 Logon Unknown Login failed for user ''. Reason: An
>   attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured
>   for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: 10.10.10.26]
>
> 10/26/2015 08:15:39 Logon Unknown Error: 18456 Severity: 14
>   State: 58.

I don't understand why the report would authenticate seemingly without any issues however, the log file states otherwise.

I would like to add that our SQL Server is configured to use mixed authentication.

Comment: Open visual cut and when it asks for your credentials, go to the server and check if the authentication error has already been logged.  Is it possible that when you try and run the report in Visual Cut, there is a data source already defined with the wrong username/passwod?  It then prompts you for valid credentials which work.  Knowing if the error occurs before you enter the credentials will prove this point.

Answer (score 2):

From Aaron Bertrand's blog on [Troubleshooting Error 18456](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456)

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.
>   Login failed for user ''. 
>   Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only.

State 58 occurs when SQL Server is set to use Windows Authentication only, and a client attempts to log in using SQL Authentication.

You have to [Change Server Authentication Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx) and **restart** sql server, if you/your software requires SQL Server authentication and your sql server is configured for Windows Authentication.

Comment: This is not the case. My server is definitely configured to use SQL Server AND Windows authentication mode. Also, I must reiterate that I CAN successfully login with SQL authentication so as to execute the report and there are no errors on the screen HOWEVER, the are still errors in the log file.

Comment: Was the authentication from installation was Mixed mode ? or did you change it ? SQL Server wont complain if you have done it right. Either way, if you changed the authentication mode then a restart is required.

Answer (score 1):

1. Has anything changed? What was your Authentication Mode originally?
2. It sounds like the SQL Server user logs in with no error.  Is there a corresponding Windows user for your VisualCut and Crystal Reports?  If so, can those users log in?
3. When you login to VisualCut the product, do you see any errors?
4. Do you see any error when in Crystal Reports? (I have to ask that because Crystal has been squirrelly ever since it was introduced.)

I'm asking you to check all of these factors because there is clearly a mismatch somewhere and it doesn't sound like this happened on Day 1.  Look at what has recently changed and work back from there.  After changing any authentication modes, privileges or credentials, restart SQLServer and any applications involved.  If you make a change to a Windows user, relogin/restart just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem that started just past 36/48 hours. I resolved access by disabling 'enforcement policy'. That let me in, but still generated log entries. I was looking for similar issue resolution in post "Log report 'bad password', but still grants access". I am beginning to think it has something to do with latest OS-update-push.